# Can a dc motor be damaged if I change the direction of the motor while on full speed?

Tags: dc, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

Can a brushless dc motor be damaged if the direction suddenly changes while the motor is already spinning in another direction?

Comment: Inertia of the rest of the system? Are the shafts capable? Or are you about to add assumptions that all is ok?

Comment: YES, thats like twice the voltage and 200x no load current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if doing so results in stresses outside the rating of the system or motor.

The controller should manage the torque, and if the system was designed properly this shouldn't cause damage.

If the controller can't absorb the regenerative energy from the reversal there could be damage. (Though this would usually damage the controller, not the motor.)

Comment: How would you apply regenerative breaking? Sorry I'm new to electronics.

Comment: If the motor is spinning in one direction, and you reverse it, all that kinetic energy has to go somewhere.  It usually winds up pumping up the DC bus on the controller, which should have enough capacitance to absorb the energy, or a resistive circuit to dissipate it. So you automatically regenerate that energy.

Comment: So I'm guessing if the motor gets reversed and I have something to harvest the kinetic energy to like a battery the motor should be fine?

Comment: Yes, assuming the mechanical system can take the stresses.